# How to add the back arrow in the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I was wondering how I could add this arrow in the action bar. I have already an action bar but can only add icons at the right hand side and is it possible to center the label?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you'd have to define the parent `Activity` for the one you'd like to display back button in. You do this via the manifest.

Do this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` somewhere within the `application` tag:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

That done, all you'd need to do is to call this on your target `Activity`, right within its `onCreate()` method:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

..or, if you happen to use `AppCompat` library in your project:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

You can refer to the official docs for up navigation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#up) for further details.

Answer (score 8):

For actionbar arrow icon:

In Activity:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In Fragment:

```
 ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Catching the click (at activity):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this two lines in your java file:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
```

;

Answer (score 1):

You can set back arrow on Action Bar by calling

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

on your activity onCreate() method.

Note: if you're using AppCompatActivity, use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar();

Answer (score 0):

Thank very much guys, no wonder I could not get it, it needs a different set-up, I thought its something you can manipulate on menu xmls

Yes, I extend mine to AppCompatActivity and got the right result using your suggestions:

```
<activity
        aandroid:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.testapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

then call

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Is there a point on answering your own question by duplicating on other's answer? Why don't you just pick one answer that worked?